# Do you need breaks in if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (condition_1)
    do_1;                                          
else if (condition_2)
    do_2;
else
    do_default;
```

I understand this. What happens though if multiple conditions return true ? Does java stop after the first true condition or do I need a break ?

Comment: It will only execute only one or none of those blocks. BTW, why can't you just execute it and see the result?

Comment: Please use braces, i.e. `if (condition_1) { 
    do_1; }
else if (condition_2) { 
    do_2; }
else { 
    do_default; }`

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat brackets are not needed if the statement only has 1 chore. (1 method to call, 1 variable to initialize, ect..)

Comment: Yes, it's always a good idea to use braces, even for single-statement clauses.  It's remarkably easy to edit another statement into an if/else without thinking about the braces and create mysterious bugs.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I know, but that doesn't you _should_ not use braces just because you _can_ not use braces.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - It's not about "needed", it's about good programming practice.

Comment: I'd like to see you try putting a break statement in the body of an if statement. : )

Comment: Of course, if the `if` statement happens to be within the body of a loop then a `break` statement will be allowed (though it may not produce the intended effect).

Answer (score 3):

Please look on If else if flowchart

[image]

Comment: You should explicitly note that the "false" leg is the "else" leg.  Otherwise, excellent graphic!

Comment: Okay, I looked at it. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

It will evaluate the boolean in order, and only run the first block that's true. That's why the syntax uses the word "else".

You are probably confusing if/else if syntax with switch/case syntax, which *does* require breaks.

Comment: Yeah, if you left out the `else` statement ahead of the second `if` then you'd get an entirely different control flow -- you'd do the second `if` test regardless of how the first turned out.  But `break` is not generally allowed in this context -- use the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, using if-then-else it will stop as soon as it hits a true statement. If none return true, the else statement is executed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

> However, once a condition is satisfied, the appropriate statements are executed and the remaining conditions are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need multiple breaks.  If the first case is true, that code is executed and the else's are skipped.  The same holds true for the else if.  So the only time the else gets executed is after the if and else if conditions have evaluated to false.

Answer (score 0):

Java will execute the first if condition (in a block of if-else if's) that satisfies the condition and will exit the block. If no condition meets the requirement, the last else statement will be executed. If there is no else statement, then none will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`break` is only for `switch` statements and loops. A string of `if-else` statements wont trigger if the condition is found. If you WANT to check for all conditions, just don't put `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple conditions returning true if you have 'parallel' ifs:

```
if (cond) {
  ...
}

if (cond) {
  ...
}
```

This is suitable when they are not mutually exclusive.

Concerning your question, why not just execute code and see for yourself ?